# MvvmCross TableView binding with custom UITableViewDelegate

Tags: mvvmcross

I have a delegate:

```
public class MyTableDelegate: UITableViewDelegate
{
    int _row;
    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        _row = indexPath.Row;
        tableView.BeginUpdates ();
        tableView.EndUpdates ();
    }

    public override float GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (indexPath.Row == _row)
            return 80;
        else
            return 60;
    }           
}
```

In my view:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource(tblUsers, UserViewCell.Key, UserViewCell.Key);
        tblUsers.Source = source;
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<UsersPopoverView, UsersPopoverViewModel>();
        tblUsers.Delegate = new MyTableDelegate ();
        set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.Users);
        set.Bind(source).For(s => s.SelectionChangedCommand).To(vm => vm.SelectUserCommand);
        set.Bind(this).For(s => s.DismissMe).To(vm => vm.Dismiss);
        set.Apply();
    }
```

When I have tblUsers.Delegate = new MyTableDelegate (); databinding is not working. How can I bind my TableView and use my custom delegate?

Comment: Try using a custom tableview source instead (it includes a delegate)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have a custom tableview source, but how can I use delegate features in it? For example I need dynamicaly change row height with animation. Could you provide some example please?

Comment: Can you not just use the `GetHeightForRow` and `RowSelected ` code shown in your question?